# How to draw a filled rectangle in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

def penup():
    for x in drawings:
        x.penup()
penup()

def drawgrass():
   for x in range(10):
        grass.goto(300,300)
        grass.color("green")
        grass.begin_fill()
        grass.forward(200)
        grass.left(300)
        grass.forward(200)
        grass.left(300)
        grass.end_fill()


penup()
drawgrass()
```

So I am creating this program that will make a landscape of some kind, and I am trying to make the grass. I was thinking of placing the cursor at 300,300, then drawing a huge rectange and then filling it making it green. So far I can not make the rectangle work, or make it cover the whole bottom half of the screen. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filling rectangles with colors in python using turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472761/filling-rectangles-with-colors-in-python-using-turtle)

Comment: `left()` is used only to turn (ie. 90 degrees) - it doesn't move (ie. 300 pixels). To create rectangle you need 4 times `forward()` and 4 times `left()` (or `right()`) .

Answer (score 1):

As in your other question, your `penup()` function makes no sense.  Here's how I might go about *filling* half the screen with green:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drawgrass():
    grass.color("green")

    width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

    grass.penup()
    grass.goto(-width/2, 0)
    grass.pendown()

    grass.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        grass.forward(width)
        grass.right(90)
        grass.forward(height/2)
        grass.right(90)

    grass.end_fill()

screen = Screen()

grass = Turtle()
grass.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

drawgrass()

grass.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

But what I would really do is *stamp* it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def drawgrass():
    grass.color('green')
    grass.shape('square')

    width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

    grass.penup()
    grass.goto(0, -height/4)
    grass.shapesize(height/2 / CURSOR_SIZE, width / CURSOR_SIZE)

    grass.stamp()

screen = Screen()

grass = Turtle()
grass.hideturtle()

drawgrass()

screen.exitonclick()
```